# Testing Disputes and Refunds in Facebook Payments

Tags: facebook, payment, facebook-credits

We're very close to launching our app and we want to test the dispute/refund process.  We've made several successful test payments however we're hesitant to dispute them.  Will our app get flagged?  What is the best way to test the dispute/refund process?

Comment: I had been hoping that payments by payment testers would be available to the payments support process (https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/dispute_payment) but since test payments do not show up as real payments, they are not listed there.

Answer (score 0):

They've listed all the documents for it here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/disputesrefunds/

I'm sure if you put in the dispute reason "This is a test for the developer: please ignore" or something or contacted Facebook and asked them they'd find a way. There is though, at present, no public method of testing dispute handling.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot test the flow end to end, you can test the integration with your backend by manually executing a POST request to `/PAYMENT_ID/refunds` with an app access token and the amount to be refunded (could be total or partial). There is no need to start a dispute through FB to be able to refund it from your app.

> If a dispute justifies a refund, you can award one using the transactions's ID and making a post to the /PAYMENT_ID/refunds with an ~app access token~ and the amount to be refunded [...] The dispute status will automatically be set to resolved with the refunded_in_cash reason.
>
> A payment doesn't necessarily have to be disputed by the consumer for you to be able to refund it. If a user contacts you directly, you can issue a refund for the payment as long as the refundable_amount is greater than the amount you're trying to refund. This functionality is also helpful when you are testing your app.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games_payments/fulfillment/disputes